# If I do not have enough reputation yet and need to add an important tag, what to do?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I tried adding the tag: 'proposal' or 'research-proposal' but could not as I do not have enough reputation yet.

What should I do?

Comment: You could provide a link to the question and someone with higher might do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask about it here on Meta, or you might comment below the question so someone with higher rep can retag it for you, if they think it is appropriate.

In the case of [research-proposal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-proposal), we do not have it yet, but we do have [grants](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grants) and [funding](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/funding), which might cover some of it.